# MYSQL trying to return duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'm trying to get my sql query to return only duplicate values from a table.

```
SELECT unitname, staff_id
FROM Unit
GROUP BY unitname, staff_id
HAVING COUNT(staff_id) >1;
```

But it keeps returning 0 rows, I don't know what to do.

Comment: 0 is possibly correct if staff id is the same but in different unitname. I would take the unitname out of the query to establish if there are duplicates on staff id.

Comment: Then there are no duplicates on `(unitname, staffid)`. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the units that have multiple staffs, then:

```
SELECT unitname, GROUP_CONCAT(staff_id)
FROM Unit
GROUP BY unitname
HAVING COUNT(staff_id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT unitname, staff_id FROM Unit HAVING COUNT(staff_id) >1 GROUP BY unitname;
```